# how to scrape custom html5 attributes

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I was scraping a site like flipkart.com. The problem is I am not able to scrape custom html5 attr. like data-src. Here is what I have done so far.

```
<?php
$link = "http://www.flipkart.com/mens-clothing/lee~brand/pr?sid=2oq%2Cs9b";
$html = file_get_html($link);
if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes))
{

    foreach ($html->find("div.pu-visual-section a img") as $el) {

 echo $a2[] = $el->data-src;

}
}
?>
```

For data-src (custom attr.) , it is returning 0, but if I change it to src, it is working fine.
Can anybody help me to expain why I am unable to scrape data-src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this line:

```
echo $a2[] = $el->data-src;
```

What you are literally doing here is `$el->data - src`, i.e. subtracting `src` from `$el->data`. `src` is treated as a constant (as it doesn't exist it's converted to string `'src'` with a notice issued)  and `$el` just doesn't have `data` field and thus converted to `null` (with a notice issued). Both arguments are converted to integers and thus you subtract 0 from 0 resulting 0.

Fix it by:

```
echo $a2[] = $el->{"data-src"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to use it as an array:

```
 echo $a2[] = $el->data-src;  ->  echo $a2[] = $el['data-src'];
```

because you are doing an arithmetic operation there..